# How can I close a Material UI Modal using an X icon rather than just by clicking outside the modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui

I am using the Material UI Modal component in my React app, and it will take up the majority of the screen (about 95%). As a result, I would like to give users a more intuitive way of closing the modal by adding a small "X" icon in the upper right of the modal and allowing that to close it. I am passing the same `handleClose` function down to this icon as I am to the Modal itself, but the function isn't even getting called when I click the icon. I checked all the props and the function is getting passed down correctly, it just isn't getting evaluated on the CloseIcon component's onClick.

Page.js

```
const Page = props => {

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    console.log('testing')
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="button" onClick={handleOpen} buttonText="Add Meal" />

      <ModalContainer
        open={open}
        handleClose={handleClose}
      >
      </ModalContainer>
    </>
  )
};
```

ModalContainer.js

```
const ModalContainer = ({
  open,
  handleClose,
  ...props
}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <StyledDialogContent>
          <ModalContent handleClose={handleClose} />
        </StyledDialogContent>

      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
};
```

ModalContent.js

```
class ModalContent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { handleClose } = this.props;
    return (

      <Container justify="center" alignItems="center">
        <ModalBody flexDirection="column" >
          <TopBar justify="flex-end" alignItems="center">
            <CloseIcon onClick={handleClose} />
          </TopBar>
          <BodyContainer>
            <FlexContainer>
              <RecipeCard />
            </FlexContainer>
            <FlexContainer>
              <MenuCard
                title="Custom Food"
                icon="https://nutriology-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/Custom-Food.svg"
                link=""
              />
            </FlexContainer>
          </BodyContainer>

        </ModalBody>
      </Container>
    )
  }
};
```

CloseIcon.js

```
const CloseIcon = props => (
  <Circle justify="center" alignItems="center">
    <Icon
      viewBox="0 0 26 26"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
      <g id="Style-Guide" stroke="none" strokeWidth="1" fillRule="evenodd">
        <g
          id="Style-Guide---Elements"
          transform="translate(-198.000000, -5239.000000)"
          strokeWidth="1.5"
        >
          <g
            id="Remove-X-icon-Default"
            transform="translate(199.000000, 5240.000000)"
          >
            <g
              id="Group"
              transform="translate(12.000000, 12.000000) rotate(-315.000000) translate(-12.000000, -12.000000) translate(6.000000, 6.000000)"
              strokeLinecap="round"
            >
              <path d="M0,6 L12,6" id="Line-2"></path>
              <path d="M6,0 L6,12" id="Line-2-Copy"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </Icon>
  </Circle>
);
```

How can I make this CloseIcon component actually call the handleClose function and close the modal?

EDIT: I added the CloseIcon.js component here for reference. However, the onClick event is firing correctly -- I tested this by replacing the handleClose function with a simple console.log and it fired appropriately on click.

Comment: Trying removing `onClose={handleClose}` from your `<Modal>` component

Comment: please post your import for CloseIcon, that might be the issue

Comment: @Ido I edited the post with the component, but I don't think it's related to that since I tested the onClick event with a generic console.log and that fired appropriately.

Comment: @dev_junwen I tried this and it did not work, but I'm not sure it would be the ideal scenario anyway since I'd still like for users to be able to close the modal by clicking outside of it in addition to the close icon.

Comment: I thought your close icon was from `@material-ui/icons` haha. Didn't know it was a custom icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CloseIcon` component doesn't handle onClick event. 
add onClick prop to `Circle` or `Icon`

```
  <Circle onClick={props.onClick} justify="center" alignItems="center">
```

or

```
 <Icon
      onClick={props.onClick}
      viewBox="0 0 26 26"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
```